# How can i use less for loops in this game and be much effective and dynamic with less lin eof codes?

Tags: python, function, for-loop, nested-lists, tic-tac-toe

```
def tic_tac_toe(board):

    mess = []   
    organize = []     
    winner = []   
    n = len(board)
```

Can i do this without this much for loops ?

```
    for i in range(len(board)):
        for j in range(len(board[i])):
            mess.append(board[j][i]) 
     #appending all vertical items


    for i in range(len(board)):
        for j in range(len(board[i])):
            mess.append(board[i][j]) 
    #appending all horizontal items


    for i in range(len(board)):
        for j in range(len(board[i])):
            i = j
            mess.append(board[i][j])
        break

    #appending items that have the same i and j index (i==0 j==0,i==1 j==1,i==2 j ==2) or better say all items in these position (\)


    for i in range(len(board)):
        for j in range(len(board[i])):
            if j - i == 2 or i - j == 2 or (i == 1 and j == 1):
                mess.append(board[i][j])  
    #appending items in these indexes : (i ==0 j ==2 , i == 1 j == 1, i ==2 j == 0) items in these position (/) 



    organize = [mess[k: k + n] for k in range(0, len(mess), n)] # creating nested list of all possible moves


    winner = ["X" if organize[i].count("X") == 3 else "O" if organize[i].count("O") == 3 else "Draw" for i in range(len(organize))] # "X" if 3 "X"s in organize[i]. "O" if 3 "O"s in organize[i] and "Draw" otherwise .
```

## and this determine winner . if one single "X" in winner list The winner is "X" . Same for "O" . but if all elemnts in winner list was "Draw" The game is a Draw .

**strong text**

```
    if "X" in winner:
        return "X"
    elif "O" in winner:
        return "O"
    elif winner.count("Draw") == 8 :
        return "Draw"  

   

print(tic_tac_toe([
    ["X", "X", "O"],
    ["O", "O", "X"],
    ["X", "X", "O"]
])) # ➞ "Draw"
```

Comment: Maybe try list comprehensions to fill your lists

Comment: @IoaTzimas I've tried but failed . Fourth for loop is overwhelming my knowledge .

Comment: One minor thing, for your third for loop, you could just use the outer loop with `mess.append(board[i][i])`

Comment: Do relations. Cols, rows and diagonals indicate three X's (or O's) with index +1 from each other, or three consecutive +4, or three consecutive +2 where one of the tiles is #6). You can check this with one nested loop with three conditions in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're happy to do it with numpy, you can simplify it a lot. Numpy allows you to rotate the board, which means you can find the horizontal lines with the same code as the vertical lines (and the same goes for the two diagonals).

```py
import numpy as np

organize = []

board_rotated = np.rot90(board).tolist() # rotate the board

organize.extend(board) # add horiztonal
organize.extend(board_rotated) # add vertical
organize.append(np.diag(board).tolist()) # add top-left to bottom-right diagonal
organize.append(np.diag(board_rotated).tolist()) # add top-right to bottom-left diagonal
```

Can be done with no for loops whatsoever, plus you don't need to have the `mess` list. Everything is added directly to `organize`.

---

What's happening is it rotates the board which allows you to perform the exact same operations on the rotated board as you do on the non-rotated board to get all of the solutions. In the example provided in the question, `board_rotated` would be:

```py
[['O', 'X', 'O'],
 ['X', 'O', 'X'],
 ['X', 'O', 'X']]
```

As expected, this has been rotated 90 degrees.
The `.extend()` function calls simply add each row to `organise`. In the case of `board` the rows are the horizontal values. The rows are the vertical values when using `board_rotated`.
Using `np.diag()` gives you the diagonal of the matrix. For `board` this is `['X', 'O', 'O']` and for `board_rotated` this is `['O', 'O', 'X']`.

Answer (score 0):

For the for loops, you can easily write 1 loop instead of 2:

instead of:

```
for i in range(len(board)):
    for j in range(len(board[i])):
        mess.append(board[j][i])
```

you can write:

```
for i, j in enumerate(board):
    mess.append(board[j][i])
```

and for sure this applies for the other for loops.

However you can also write a function to reduce the number of for loops.